# Does Intel H61 chipset supports Intel Integrated graphics?

Tags: cpu, integrated-graphics, chipset, intel-core-i3

I am about to get a motherboard with the Intel H61 chipset and the Intel i3 2100 CPU.

Can these two comunicate and use the Cpu's integrated graphics?
According to [this](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/h61-express-chipset.html) it is possible but I am kinda lost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it does support the integrated GPU. You should probably see the VGA/DVI/HDMI connectors on the motherboard you gonna buy.